# How do I run a check to see if my player ISN'T colliding with an object?

Tags: c#, xna, collision

I'm on my way to finishing another feature in my XNA game, but I was wondering how you're supposed to check and see if the player has stopped intersecting with an object.

At the moment, I have a `bool` that is true when the player intersects with an asteroid i.e. hiding behind it. But I need to find out when the player has stopped intersecting with said asteroid to allow the `bool` to return to false and allow a different movement path for my enemies.

Code so far:

```
    Rectangle rectangle1;
    Rectangle rectangle2;

    rectangle1 = new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X, (int)player.Position.Y, player.Width, player.Height);

    for (int i = 0; i < asteroids.Count; i++)
    {
        rectangle2 = new Rectangle((int)asteroids[i].Position.X, (int)asteroids[i].Position.Y, asteroids[i].Width, asteroids[i].Height);

        if (rectangle1.Intersects(rectangle2))
        {
            hidden = true;
        }
    }
```

I just don't know how to check for the other state. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd change this approach slightly.

Firstly don't declare a rectangle every frame. Instead create the rectangles when creating the asterioids and player. Then in each respective update, update the rectangle's position with the entities position.

So rectangle1 is now player.rectangle (I'd recommend get sets but for the purpose of this, it's not a concern) and rectangle2 is asteroid.rectangle.

Next I would make one of two changes. If you're only concerned about checking that a collision has occurred, change the boolean to false at the start before the check is performed. Should no collision occur, that boolean will stay false, if however a collision has been performed that boolean should be changed to true and then you need to use the break keyword to get out of the loop.

```
// ensure rectangle's positions reflect the entity's position before checking.
hidden = false;

for (int i = 0; i < asteroids.Count; i++)
{
    if (player.rectangle.Intersects(asteroids[i].rectangle))
    {
        hidden = true;
    }
}
```

Or if you need to check for multiple collisions, I would use a slightly different approach. If a collision has occurred I would store the asteroid's position to then use later to determine how to affect the player movement. This would allow multiple collisions to be handled at once. You might still need the boolean for other reasons so I've kept that, but you could just check to see how many elements are in the list. I'd also note, to handle collisions with more accuracy more data such as mass, gravity etc would be required but that's a whole separate topic.

```
// ensure rectangle's positions reflect the entity's position before checking.

List<Vector2> collisionPositions = new List<Vector2> positions;
hidden = false;

for (int i = 0; i < asteroids.Count; i++)
{
    if (player.rectangle.Intersects(asteroids[i].rectangle))
    {
        hidden = true;
        collisionPositions.add(asteroids[i].position);

    }
}
```